# Adding purchaseables to cart with custom matrix field

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce2

When I follow the documented process of [populating custom fields](https://craftcms.com/docs/commerce/4.x/orders-carts.html#storing-data-in-custom-fields) with an update cart call, I'm able to get values for lightswitches and text fields to populate just fine. I cannot, however, get the submitted fields to carry over to the order/cart when I try to populate them into a Matrix field.

Is this possible with Commerce?

In this case, I'm trying to capture a manifest of individuals (name, email, phone) based on the quantity.

If I try to add:

```
    <div class="form-group">
      {% tag 'input' with {
          type: 'email',
          name: 'fields[manifest][blocks][new1][fields][firstName]',
          value: "",
          placeholder: 'First Name'|t,
          class: ['form-control']
      } %}{% endtag %}
      <label for="fields[manifest][blocks][new1][fields][firstName]">{{ 'First Name'|t }}</label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      {% tag 'input' with {
          type: 'email',
          name: 'fields[manifest][blocks][new1][fields][lastName]',
          value: "",
          placeholder: 'First Name'|t,
          class: ['form-control']
      } %}{% endtag %}
      <label for="fields[manifest][blocks][new1][fields][lastName]">{{ 'Last Name'|t }}</label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      {% tag 'input' with {
          type: 'email',
          name: 'fields[manifest][blocks][new1][fields][email]',
          value: "",
          placeholder: 'Email'|t,
          class: ['form-control']
      } %}{% endtag %}
      <label for="fields[manifest][blocks][new1][fields][email]">{{ 'Email'|t }}</label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      {% tag 'input' with {
          type: 'email',
          name: 'fields[manifest][blocks][new1][fields][phone]',
          value: "",
          placeholder: 'Email'|t,
          class: ['form-control']
      } %}{% endtag %}
      <label for="fields[manifest][blocks][new1][fields][phone]">{{ 'Phone #'|t }}</label>
    </div>
```

If I replace `new1` with a unique key to identify each one, I would expect it to add each of the values to a matching block for the manifest custom field but it doesn't seem to be capturing the input at all.

Craft CMS: 4.4.6.1
Craft Commerce: 4.2.6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured out the issue. In order to work with a matrix field, you also have to include the block type and the sortOrder in the POST data.

```
{{ input('hidden', 'fields[manifest][sortOrder][]', '__counter__') }}
{{ input('hidden', 'fields[manifest][blocks][new1][type]', 'manifest') }}
    <div class="form-group">
      {% tag 'input' with {
          type: 'email',
          name: 'fields[manifest][blocks][new1][fields][firstName]',
          value: "",
          placeholder: 'First Name'|t,
          class: ['form-control']
      } %}{% endtag %}
      <label for="fields[manifest][blocks][new1][fields][firstName]">{{ 'First Name'|t }}</label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      {% tag 'input' with {
          type: 'email',
          name: 'fields[manifest][blocks][new1][fields][lastName]',
          value: "",
          placeholder: 'First Name'|t,
          class: ['form-control']
      } %}{% endtag %}
      <label for="fields[manifest][blocks][new1][fields][lastName]">{{ 'Last Name'|t }}</label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      {% tag 'input' with {
          type: 'email',
          name: 'fields[manifest][blocks][new1][fields][email]',
          value: "",
          placeholder: 'Email'|t,
          class: ['form-control']
      } %}{% endtag %}
      <label for="fields[manifest][blocks][new1][fields][email]">{{ 'Email'|t }}</label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      {% tag 'input' with {
          type: 'email',
          name: 'fields[manifest][blocks][new1][fields][phone]',
          value: "",
          placeholder: 'Email'|t,
          class: ['form-control']
      } %}{% endtag %}
      <label for="fields[manifest][blocks][new1][fields][phone]">{{ 'Phone #'|t }}</label>
    </div>
```

Adding those fields solved the problem.